# What are undeclared and undefined variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

All I've understood is that

***Undeclared variable***:

```
z = 100;
```

here when *var*,*let* and *const* are not used its undeclared variable.

***Undefined variable***:

```
var y;
y=y+1;
```

Here since y is not given a value .Its undefined variable.
Please correct

Comment: No need for correction, you've got it right. What is your question?

Comment: Btw `var y;` is short for `var y = undefined;` so that might make it more obvious

Comment: @Bergi         My question is that  "What are _undeclared_ and _undefined variables_ in Javascript?"

Comment: And yet you already answer this question with "*variable not declared with `var`/`let`/`const`*" and "*variable not given a value/having the value `undefined`*".